# Identifying these ICs

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-electronics, identification

Points go to someone who can identify these ICs. Both 6-pin controllers for switching regulators 12VDC in. The first one looks like 12V out, the second is 3.3V out. They're in a router.

Markings:
TH4cZ4
GC13NR

[image: 1st]
[image: 2nd]

The reason I want to know is to find out is to find out the range of import voltages that it could handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top ones markings match with a [TMI (拓尔微) TMI3244T](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2010161906_TMI-TMI3244T_C840542.pdf) step-down converter.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [szlcsc.com](https://item.szlcsc.com/896927.html))

---

The bottom ones markings matches with a [Fitipower FR9205](https://file2.dzsc.com/product/22/11/26/310432_164907819.pdf) step-down converter.

[image]

[image]

(source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_Fitipower-Integrated-Tech-FR9205S6_C5162515.html))

Comment: Thank you so much. Looks like they're good up to 18V, so that's great news.